# Finding ViewPager is loaded or not in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

Hi I am stuff playing with ViewPager.

In my project, the class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter.
MyPagerAdapter's instantiateItem method looks like below.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext

    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_layout,
            container, false);

    slideImage = new ImageView(mContext);
    slideImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.helpscreen_image);

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(mMusicPromoBean.get(position).getImageUrl())
            .into(slideImage);

    container.addView(view);


    return view;
}
```

The viewpager_layout.xml contains an ImageView.

The ViewPager working fine. But the image loading into the ViewPager takes 5 to 7 seconds sometimes.So that I decided to show a loader above the viewPager.

But I want notified that the Viewpager's imageview not yet loaded by image.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`Picasso` has quite convenient method `into` which accepts not only `ImageView` but `Callback` instance.

```
ImageView imageView;
Picasso.with(this).load("").into(
        imageView,
        new Callback() {
            @Override public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override public void onError() {

            }
        }
);
```

So `onSuccess` will be called when image was loaded successfully.